# Update statement errors, parenthesis, failed validation ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am writing an update query and it is giving me errors, what i am trying to do is to take a value multiply it added to another value.

**Original statement**

The statement below works flawlessly,

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
```

**Modified version not working**
This is the modified version,  i want to multiply the first two select with a value in each field for in flight and outfight seats no.

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL(((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0)) +
   NVL(((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0)* NVL(R.OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0)) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
```

Comment: I don't see a trigger, only an UPDATE statement.

Comment: yes indeed, got confused very tired :(

Comment: So, your question is only about the UDATE statement?

Comment: indeed just take whats in `NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0)` multiply it by R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO and do the same for the other and then add the values from the three selects

Comment: Update, sorry i forgot to edit the title and content

Answer (score 1):

Editor, that higlights matching braces should do the trick.
There are just too many of them. And... You left out the default values in outer `nvl()` or `nvl` keyword itself?

```
...
NVL(
 "nvl here?"(
  (SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0
 )
 * NVL(R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0)
",default value here?") + ...
```

Go, have a break. This happens to me very often :-)